# Looping the table in c# given all the values..?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, html-agility-pack, xmldocument

I've table like this

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Header1</td>
       <td>Header2</td>
       <td>Header3</td>
       <td>Header4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>11</td>
       <td>22</td>
       <td>33</td>
       <td>44</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

My code is

```
var headersList = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("//table//tbody//tr").ToList();
```

But headerlist is giving all the td values :-(

Now I would like to know how can loop this table. My expected result as below:

First loop expected result

```
Header1 = 1,
Header2 = 2,
Header3 = 3,
Header4 = 4,
```

Second loop expected result:

```
Header1 = 11
Header2 = 22
Header3 = 33
Header4 = 44
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no way to distinguish between header and body (lack of `thead`, `tbody`) you will need to determine the number of elements programmatically.

```
var data = @"<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Header1</td>
       <td>Header2</td>
       <td>Header3</td>
       <td>Header4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>11</td>
       <td>22</td>
       <td>33</td>
       <td>44</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(data);
var headerElements = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//table//tbody//tr");
int headerCount = headerElements.First().Descendants().Count();
var nodes = headerElements.SelectMany(x => x.Descendants())
                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                          .ToList();
var head = nodes.Take(headerCount).ToList();
var body = nodes.Skip(headerCount).ToList();

var pairs = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();

for(var i = 0; i < body.Count; i += headerCount)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < head.Count; j++)
    {
        pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(head[j], body[i+j]));
    }
}

foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Comment: The algorithm is generic, but if you have an uneven amount of elements per row you will need to modify the `for` loop to account for that.

Comment: Yeah I did. Just taken the head and loop in different way. Apparently I don't need body and pair list.I wrote the the body for different way. Anyhow thanx very much sharing this code and its very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet) to parse HTML documents. Here is sample of displaying table data to console:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path_to_html);
var rows = 
      doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr")
         .Select(tr => tr.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerHtml).ToList())
         .ToList();
```

Output:

```
var headers = rows[0];

// skip first row which contains headers
foreach (var row in rows.Skip(1))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
        if (headers.Count > i) // you can remove this check if data is valid
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", headers[i], row[i]);
}
```

Result:

```
Header1 = 1
Header2 = 2
Header3 = 3
Header4 = 4

Header1 = 11
Header2 = 22
Header3 = 33
Header4 = 44
```

---

If you need to define headers for columns, then I suggest you to use `thead` tag:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <td>Header1</td>
       <td>Header2</td>
       <td>Header3</td>
       <td>Header4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>11</td>
       <td>22</td>
       <td>33</td>
       <td>44</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In this case parsing and output will look like

```
var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/thead/tr/td")
                 .Select(td => td.InnerHtml).ToList();
var rows = 
      doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tbody/tr")
         .Select(tr => tr.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerHtml).ToList())
         .ToList();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", headers[i], row[i]);
}
```

Comment: with thead its very easy but my file doesn't have thead. :-( with out Thead i can't get my output?

Comment: @user1990395 you can, use same approach, but iterate over first row instead of headers collection. See updated answer

Comment: I'm trying this and let you know once it is succeeded